# Switching Wordpress theme live without losing functionality

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to change my Wordpress theme to give my site a new look. The new theme comes with lots more features than the old one.

I know how to install and activate the new theme. When I do this, I have to customise the home page and other pages.

Is there a way to make this transition while the site remains live without publishing the new theme until all the customisation is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natively? No. Any widget areas that aren't registered will have their widgets moved to "Inactive Widgets". Any custom functionality/options that aren't in the new theme won't show up. Unless the two themes have a specific "import from x" functionality, your best bet is to set up a development environment and then clone that when you're ready.

There are dozens of plugins and utilities that will let you backup/migrate/clone/restore your site.

I'd recommend setting up `dev.your-site.com` and cloning your current site there. Then activate the new theme, make all the changes you want/need to, and then when that's ready, clone it and deploy it it on `your-site.com`. That way you only have a few seconds of downtime instead of a partially empty/broken site while you manage all the changes you want.